# Adjusting URL showed in address bar with routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I would like to optimize my URL showed in web browsers. I know Routing is perfect for that but I don't know if it is possible the way I want. I have a list of projects in a list. Each project have an ID, a name and a category. When navigating to the detail product page, the URL showed should be "/category/name". I know I can pass the ID, the category and the name in the ActionLink and adjusting the routing in Global.asax. I already do that but I still have the ID which is concatenate to the rest of the URL. This is ugly.

**Here is an example:**

The ActionLink in my view:

```
@Html.ActionLink(@p.Name, "Detail", new { projectID = @p.ProjectID, category = @p.Category, name = @p.Name })
```

the Global.asax:

```
routes.MapRoute(null,
    "{category}/{name}",       
    new { controller = "Project", action = "Detail" }
);
```

The resulting URL:

[image]

As you can see, the projectID is always added to the end of the URL. How can I avoid that behaviour?

Thanks.

Comment: If category and name are sufficient, why do you need to pass projectId in your ActionLink?

Comment: @counsellorben: category and name are interesting to show in the URL in the address bar. ProjectID is necessary in the action controller to get the right project to pass to the detail view.

Comment: Then you should accept rouen's answer, since it will provide a clean URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
routes.MapRoute(null,
"{category}/{name}/{projectID}",       
new { controller = "Project", action = "Detail", projectID = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

);

will give you

```
/INDUSTRIE/Mailing/16
```

is that what you want ?

Comment: No, In the view, I would like to create an ActionLink with several things (projectID, name, category). projectID is used in the action controller to get the right project. Next, in the URL I don't wanna see the projectID. I think this is not possible.